# Silverlight 2: Text Glow effect?

Tags: silverlight, graphics

I'd like to create an outer-glow (or halo) effect on a text block in Silverlight.

(For PS3 users, something similar to the glow around the menu text on that system).

I've seem samples to do inner and outer glow on other shapes, such as rectangles but this does not translate to text.

Just wondering if anyone has pointers to help me.

Comment: Would you want the glow on hover?

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never. Check out this potential solution:

http://puremsil.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/glow-effect-in-silverlight/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Blacklight project at http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight. They have support for inner and outer glows.